# How to extract a function definitions /contents in a given c/ cpp file using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I scratched my head enough to get the below result.
Say I have a .c file like below:

```
file.c
int fun1()
{
  int x = 3;
  return x;}
void f2()
{
   int x= 7; 
   int y =0;
}
```

Can someone help on how to get only function names along with body and write them into some other file ?
I tried ctags, grep etc.. I got only function names but not the body

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone help on how to get only function names along with body and write them into some other file ? I tried ctags, grep etc.. I got only function names but not the body

You need something that really understands the syntax. Grep and consorts are not capable of parsing C or C++ (there's mathematical descriptions of the type of languages a regular expression engine can parse, same for awk and so on, and C isn't in that class of languages, and C++ is much harder than C to parse).

`ctags` is pure unadulterated early 1990's technology (translate that into age, and language versions of C and C++ since then, and you'll see why it's questionable to rely on it today). Mostly "heuristics" based on parsers that are in fact too simple to fully "understand" C or C++. Also, as you noticed, concerned with knowing *where* a symbol is, not the *contents* of any function. (I've worked with exuberant ctags, which had its last release 2009, so can't possibly parse C++11++ or C11++, but I hear better things about universal ctags, but that's still a text-based tool without context information, which just can't deal with polymorphism, cross-file templates, and basically all the nice things that C++ post 2003 brought for medium to large projects.)

The bad news hence is that you need more or less a full C compiler (or a full C++ compiler), minus the actual translation to machine language. So, chances are you can never write something that works well yourself; a team of one is a bit too small to implement such complex languages.

The **good** news is that someone else already invented a *general* way to enable tools (like IDEs, linters, syntax checkers…) to access rather potent language parsers, and there's a lot of language parsers to choose from, and especially good ones for C++.
(I'd argue of these two pretty different languages, C++ is the harder one, so that there's C++ support is the surprising one; as a matter of fact, while C syntax isn't a subset of C++, the remainder subtraction of C++ from C is small enough that you'll be fine using a C++ parser to get the contents of C functions, unless you're really going for pre-ANSI C styles.)

There's the [*language server protocol*](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) (LSP), and it's how (neo)vim, emacs, Spyder, VSCode, Kate… get all their "jump to declaration", "highlight mistakes", "show the definition inline" functionalities: By querying a *languages server* using LSP about the things it sees (`clangd` is the LSP server for C++ of choice).

And you can do the same! LSP is not a complex protocol. As a matter of fact, it's just a bunch of JSON-RPC requests (JSON-RPC: think "REST", but instead of HTTP you use something simpler, and instead of "general, whatever", it's always JSON as payload). So, either, you find a JSON-RPC command line client, start `clangd` manually in your scripting and make requests to that (using the LSP language) using that CLI client, or you just take an existing client with a CLI interface and use that.

There's probably little efficiency to be gained here from coding the client yourself, considering the complexity certainly doesn't like in the client, but in the LSP server that needs to parse C++ (and C). So, I'd just push neovim or emacs into a background/daemon mode, and interact with their scripting interfaces (neovim: Lua, emacs: elisp).

I **bet** you hoped this would be as simple as running

```bash
cool_tool \
  -symbol-content "myns::containers::coolcont<Owlfeet>::hoot(int, int, std::string)" \
  -source-file owls.cc
```

and getting the `hoot` function's content back, but sadly in C++ projects, to even know how your symbol is formed, which overload is implemented in which file, and which things are even candidates for being the implementation of some function, that you need to have an overview over all the software module's compilation units, includes etc. So, you really must think of a C++ parser as something that kind of falls flat if you don't use it together with knowledge of how things would be compiled — and that's why C++ LSP tools are typically well-integrated in IDEs, and nothing you can isolatedly just call for a couple files; sorry to be the bringer of that kind of bad news. A lot of work in `clangd`, which uses the clang compiler's language understanding internally, goes into not having to parse every file that gets included a 1000 times, even if it did not change, or isn't relevant.

Make use of the rather slim neovim as "CLI-izable" IDE, and you'll be fine. It's just not a single command line tool that really works well that I could recommend.

Generally, if you're dealing with complex data like C and C++ source code, maybe a shell script simply isn't the tool you want to build. Feels like a pretty under-versartile language to write something that deals with a pretty versatile language!

Comment: Now it makes sense. Very nice explanation. Thanks a lot